# Can I use AWS Polly from the CLI to read from a text file in an S3 bucket directly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface, text-to-speech, amazon-polly

I'd like to be able to use 'aws polly synthesize-speech' on my terminal in order to produce an mp3 file that reads a txt file located in an S3 bucket.

Currently running the following and it outputs an mp3 file in my Downloads folder:

> aws polly synthesize-speech --text 'hello how are you?'
> --output-format mp3 --voice-id Emma ~/Downloads/speech.mp3

However, I want to be able to read a txt file **inside an S3 bucket** as opposed to hardcoding 'hello how are you?' directly like I have done above. Does anyone have any idea how to do it?

Comment: Do you mean something like `aws polly synthesize-speech --text "$(aws s3 cp s3://example-bucket/object -)" ...` ?

Comment: yes, exactly that! thanks a lot